# Unit test Angular mock HTML Document

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, frontend, jasmine

I have one method in my `component.ts` and i would like to know how can i test the method below:

```
print(i) {
    (document.getElementById("iframe0) as any).contentWindow.print();
}
```

I don't know how to mock html document with one iframe to call this method.

Anyone knows....

i would like to know how to mock document html to create for example one instance and check if my method is printing html document.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in the code? Missing `"` after iframe0, and is the `0` intentional or is that the key that was hit by mistake?

It looks to me as it should be

```
print(i) {
    (document.getElementById("iframe0") as any).contentWindow.print();
}
```

Comment: It really was a typo. When I try to run the above implementation I am getting the following error: Type Error: cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null.

Comment: is the name of your iframe "iframe" or "iframe0"

Comment: and what are your intentions with the input variable (i)?